# Python: pipenv Error (ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/LGIT/$USERPROFILE$/Local/Programs/Python2/Python27/Scripts/python.exe')

Tags: python, pipenv

I just switched from using venv to pipenv.
But after I installed pipven through pip:

```
python -m pip install pipenv
```

I moved to my new project directory and done creating the virtual environment via:

```
pipenv shell
```

Then receive the following error message:

```
...
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Python2/Python27/Scripts/python.exe'
```

I have check the "Environment Variables" and I set it right. How can I solve this Problems? Many Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try `python3 -m pip install pipenv`. I think there is a path error here.

Comment: I already install pipenv

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem, by using older version of pipenv:

```
pip install pipenv==2018.10.13
```

I don't know why this happen but it work with me